# Need approach on how to write Button text based on nested multiple conditions , actions performed on each state of button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-structures, design-patterns, sonarqube

For Example , consider the shopping cart.

1. Button text will be displayed as "Get" item , when cart is empty & selected item is not purchased.(these may be multiple nested conditions)
2. Button text will be displayed as "Purchase more" item, if it's purchased && want to add more.
3. Button text will be displayed as "Download" , if its purchased successfully.

And respective action based on text.

To get button Text  used below code

```
const btnText = "GET";

if(condition1 && condition2 ){
   btnText = "Install"
} else if(abc(condition3 || condition4)){
    btnText = "Manage"
}else if(){
}else{
 btnText = "Purchase"
}
```

To get button action

```
if(condition1 || condition 3){
dispatch(action)
} else if()
```

I dont want this way either, where I tried with Map in Javascript & switch to perform actions on it.

```
const btnText = new Map()
       .set('Install',  condition1 && condition2)
       .set('Manage',abc(condition3 || condition4));
```

But need better solution than this.
Which will be scalable and reliable so even if business scenario gets added easily add and read the code.

Which data structure to use instead of multiple conditions to avoid #sonarqube Refactor this function to reduce its Cognitive Complexity. ?

Otherwise which pattern to follow to write such code in #ReactJS , #JS.

Comment: what u tried so far? share some code. u got any errors?

Comment: There can be a lot of answers to this question, but it all depends on what your test conditions actually looks like. My best guess with the little code you've provided would be to create an object with the text to display, lambda expressions for your tests, and the operator to apply to the function (&&, ||) etc. But it has some limitations, and I can't say for sure it would really be a solution without more information.